# What does the !== operator do?

Tags: php, operators

What does this `!==` mean in php and is there any doc's on it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/3737139/212218

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[PHP comparison operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php), "Not identical" (5th in the table)

This operator works much like != but also checks the *type* of the operands. For example:
`3 != '3'` is `false`, but `3 !== '3'` is `true`.

Answer (score 5):

`==` is the comparison operator you're familiar with: if two values are equivalent, they `==` each other. There's some type coercion that goes on before the comparison.

```
4 == '4' // true: equivalent value, different type
```

`===` is a more strict comparison that requires that values be of the same type.

```
4 === 4 // true: same value, same type
'4' === '4' // true: same value, same type
4 === '4' // false: equivalent value, different type
```

`!==` is the opposite of the strict comparison operator, so it is true when two values are of a different type or different value or both.

```
4 !== 3 // true: different value, same type
4 !== '4' // true: equivalent value, different type
'4' !== 3 // true: different value, different type
'4' !== '3' // true: different value, same type
4 !== 4 // false: same value, same type
```

Answer (score 2):

It means "not equal or not the same type".

This shows the difference between `!=` and `!==`:

```
"5"!=5 //returns false
"5"!==5 //returns true
```

Comment: As a side note, the corresponding equality operators are: `==` and `===`

Answer (score 1):

That is the not identical operator

```
$a !== $b
```

Returns TRUE if $a is not equal to $b, or they are not of the same type.

For example, it is used to check if a variable is false and not 0, since 0 is the same that false for PHP.

```
$bar = 0;
if ($bar != false) { echo '$bar != false'; } // won't output the text
if ($bar !== false) { echo '$bar !== false'; } // will output the text
```

Comment: Indeed, particularly useful if a function can return an resulting integer on success or false on failure. You will need to check "!== false" as "!= false" could be success and returning the integer 0;

Answer (score 0):

`!=` is used for value only 
but 
`!==` is used for value and type both

suppose:

```
$a = "5"; // String
$b = 5;   // Integer

$a!=$b    // false
$a!==$b   // true
```

That's the difference.